# Reducing one level of array and also getting response like laravel paginate

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, formatting

I am trying to implement advance search in Laravel but stuck in an issue the issue is that I want to filter through multiple tables to get records and store them in some array for displaying. I have an array of data needed to display just that it is in wrong format I need to format it according to Laravel paginate.

Here is the code I am trying.

```
public static function getHeaderSearchedResults($term) {
    $resultArray = array();
    $searchable_ids = array();
    $subjects = SheetSubject::where('subject_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->get(['subject_id'])->toArray();
    $units = SheetUnit::where('unit_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->get(['id'])->toArray();
    $years = SheetYear::where('year_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->get(['year_id'])->toArray();
    $sheets = Sheet::where('sheet_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $term . '%')->get(['sheet_id'])->toArray();

    $finalArray = array_merge($subjects, $units, $years, $sheets);

    foreach ($finalArray as $ids) {
        foreach ($ids as $id) {
            array_push($searchable_ids, $id);
        }
    }
    dump($searchable_ids);
    foreach ($searchable_ids as $new_id) {
        $sheet = Sheet::where('sheet_subject_id', $new_id)
                        ->orwhere('sheet_unit_id', $new_id)
                        ->orwhere('sheet_year_id', $new_id)
                        ->orwhere('sheet_id', $new_id)
                        ->orwhere('sheet_s_id', $new_id)
                        ->orderBy('sheet_title', 'asc')->paginate(12);
        dump($new_id);
        array_push($resultArray, $sheet);
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

**The Response I am Getting is Like:**

```
array:15 [▼
       0 => LengthAwarePaginator {#273 ▶}
       1 => LengthAwarePaginator {#278 ▶}
       2 => LengthAwarePaginator {#251 ▶}
       3 => LengthAwarePaginator {#294 ▶}
       4 => LengthAwarePaginator {#308 ▶}
       5 => LengthAwarePaginator {#322 ▼
#total: 35
#lastPage: 3
#items: Collection {#351 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▶]
}
#perPage: 12
#currentPage: 1
#path: "http://localhost:8000/primary-resources"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
}
6 => LengthAwarePaginator {#275 ▶}
7 => LengthAwarePaginator {#364 ▶}
8 => LengthAwarePaginator {#367 ▶}
9 => LengthAwarePaginator {#370 ▶}
10 => LengthAwarePaginator {#373 ▶}
11 => LengthAwarePaginator {#376 ▶}
12 => LengthAwarePaginator {#379 ▶}
13 => LengthAwarePaginator {#382 ▶}
14 => LengthAwarePaginator {#385 ▼
#total: 1
#lastPage: 1
#items: Collection {#377 ▶}
#perPage: 12
#currentPage: 1
#path: "http://localhost:8000/primary-resources"
#query: []
#fragment: null
#pageName: "page"
}
]
```

**The Response I Want is like this:**

```
LengthAwarePaginator {#248 ▼
 #total: 5548
 #lastPage: 463
 #items: Collection {#257 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
   0 => Sheet {#258 ▶}
   1 => Sheet {#259 ▶}
   2 => Sheet {#260 ▶}
   3 => Sheet {#261 ▶}
   4 => Sheet {#262 ▶}
   5 => Sheet {#263 ▶}
   6 => Sheet {#264 ▶}
   7 => Sheet {#265 ▶}
   8 => Sheet {#266 ▶}
   9 => Sheet {#267 ▶}
   10 => Sheet {#268 ▶}
   11 => Sheet {#269 ▶}
 ]
}
 #perPage: "12"
 #currentPage: 1
 #path: "http://localhost:8000/primary-resources"
 #query: []
 #fragment: null
 #pageName: "page"
}
```

Anyone who knows what is it that I am doing wrong. would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.